# Linux-About sorting shell output

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have output from a customised log file like this:

```
8 24 yum
8 24 yum
8 24 make
8 24 make
8 24 cd
8 24 cd
8 25 make
8 25 make
8 25 make
8 26 yum
8 26 yum
8 26 make
8 27 yum
8 27 install
8 28 ./linux
8 28 yum
```

I'd like to know if there's anyway to count the number of specific values of the third field. For example I may want to count the number of `cd`,`yum` and `install` **only**.

Comment: @What field represents the value of the third? Or are you counting the number of instances (lines) for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` to do get the third field values and `wc -l` to count the number.

```
awk '$3=="cd"||$3=="yum"||$3=="install"||$3=="cat" {print $0}' file | wc -l
```

You can also use `egrep`, but this will look for these words not only on the third field, but everywhere else in the line.

```
egrep "(cd|yum|install|cat)" file | wc -l
```

if you want to count a specific word on the third field, then you can do the above without multiple regexs.

```
awk '$3=="cd" {print $0}' | wc -l
```

Comment: That more or less works when the list of names is known in advance and is small.  It is not good when the list is not known in advance.  The question does say 'for example', suggesting that the list is not fixed.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan Leffler. It was my fault that I didn't make it clear. The list is not fixed. But the specific values are fixed. Thank you @iamauser.

Answer (score 1):

A classic shell script to do the job is:

```
awk '{print $3}' "$file" | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Extract values from column 3 with `awk`, sort the identical names together, count the repeats, sort the output in increasing order of count.  The `sort | uniq -c | sort -n` part is a common meme.

If you're using GNU `awk`, you can do it all in the `awk` script; it might be more efficient, but for really humungous files, it can run out of memory where the pipeline doesn't (`sort` spills to disk when necessary; writing code to spill to disk in `awk` is not sensible).

Answer (score 1):

Use `cut`, `sort` and `uniq`:

```
$ cut -d" " -f3 inputfile | sort | uniq -c
      2 cd
      1 install
      1 ./linux
      6 make
      6 yum
```

Comment: It referred to the inputfile.  Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` to count the occurrences of field three and `sort` to order the output:

```
$ awk '{a[$3]++}END{for(k in a)print a[k],k}' file | sort -n 
1 install
1 ./linux
2 cd
6 make
6 yum
```

So filter by command:

```
$ awk '/cd|yum|install/{a[$3]++}END{for(k in a)print a[k],k}' file | sort -n
1 install
2 cd
6 yum
```

To stop partial matches such as `grep` in `egrep` use word boundaries `\<` and `\>` so the filter would be `/\<cd\>|\<yum\>|\<install\>/`

Comment: Thanks! But this sorts all the values in $3. Can I count "cd","yum" and "install" only?

Comment: So does most of the other answers you should have been clearer. Luckily this is trivial with `awk` see update.

Answer (score 0):

For your input this

```
awk '{++a[$3]}END{for(i in a)print i "\t" a[i];}' file
```

Would print:

```
cd      2
install 1
./linux 1
make    6
yum     6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` to filter by multiple terms at the same time:

```
cut -f3 -d' ' file | grep -x -e yum -e make -e install | sort | uniq -c
```

Explanation:

- The `-x` flag is to match only the lines that match exactly, as if with `^pattern$`
- The `cut` extracts the 3rd column only
- We `sort`, `uniq` with count in the end for efficiency, after all junk is removed from the input

Answer (score -1):

i guess u want to count the values of `yum` `install` & `cd` separately. if so, u shud go for 3 separate awk statements: 
`awk '$3=="cd" {print $0}' file | wc -l 

awk '$3=="yum" {print $0}' file | wc -l 

awk '$3=="install" {print $0}' file | wc -l`